# Riemann Integral Upper vs Lower Estimate. Inf vs sup?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

We're currently going through the Riemann integral in my real analysis course. We've defined $$\overline{\int}f \,dx = \inf\ U(P,f)$$
$$\underline{\int}f \,dx = \sup\ L(P,f)$$
Where $U(P,f)$ is the upper approximation and $L(P,f)$ is the lower approximation.
I'm not entirely sure why we're taking the $\inf$ of the upper approximation and the $\sup$ of the lower approximation. It makes sense intuitively but I've been trying to think through it geometrically and I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following image:

[image]

The expression $U(f,P)$ approximates the area under the graph of $f$ using rectangles whose heights on each interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ are given by $\sup_{x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)$. Hence, by definition the heights of the rectangles always exceed (or maybe equal to) the value of the function on each interval so you get an overestimate of the area (whatever it may be). As the partition gets finer and finer, you get better approximations which still generally are overestimating the area under the graph of $f$ and so you it makes sense to consider the infimum of all such approximations. In the image, you can see two such overestimates on the left which correspond to two different partitions of $[a,b]$.

Similarly, the expression $L(f,P)$ approximates the area under the graph of $f$ by using rectangles whose heights on each interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ are given by $\inf_{x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)$. Hence, by definition the heights of the rectangles are always less than (or maybe equal to) the value of the function on each interval so you get an underestimate of the area. As the partition gets finer and finer, you get better approximations which still generally are underestimates of the area and so in this case it makes sense to consider the supremum of all such approximations. In the image, two such underestimates are calculated on the right using two different partitions.

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Completely makes sense now. Too bad Rudin doesn't have this :)

Comment: @YevgeniyFeyman: Yeah, Rudin is sparse on pictures and motivation.

Comment: Sparse? Nowhere a single picture!! Ugh. To work with Rudin, you absolutely have to draw pictures of everything (unless you have no visual intuition).

Comment: @levap How can the height be equal to the value of the function? Do you mean the average?

Comment: @user599310: For the case of the upper sums, on each interval, the height of the rectangle is equal to the supremum of the function over that interval. When the function is continuous (as in the images above), the height of the rectangle is equal to the **maximum value** of the function in that interval, not the **average value** (consider the images on the left). In fact, you usually define the "average" of the function in terms of integrals so you can't use that when you define the integral itself as this will be circular reasoning.

Comment: @levap The "greater or equal" is what bothered me. As you said it would be circular reasoning to refer to the average value. How do we know that area is "exactly" the limit of Riemann sum? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not exactly a question of "knowing". You **define** the area as the limit of Riemann sums (provided that both exist, then they coincide) and then verify that it satisfies various properties that correspond to the intuitive notion of area. What is "area" anyway? Everyone agrees what is the area of a square or a rectangle, but if I draw you some irregular shape on paper and ask you what is the area, what would you do? You can divide the paper into a a square grid and count the areas of the small squares that intersect the shape. Intuitively, this will give you an over-approximation of

Comment: the area, and if you draw a smaller square grid and repeat the procedure, you should get better and better approximations to the "area", whatever it is. In math, this logic is turned around and the approximation process is taken to be the definition of an area.