# If the Partition $P\subset P'$, then $L(f, P)\leq L(f, P')$ and $U(f, P))\geq U(f, P')$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, partitions-for-integration

I have this proof but I don't really understand it, mathematically and visually (if that makes sense).

So the **definition** is:

A partition $P'$ is a refinement of the partition $P$ is $P\subset P'$.

And the **Lemma** is:

If $P\subset P'$, then $L(f, P)\leq L(f, P')$ and $U(f, P)\geq U(f, P')$

Here's the **Proof**:

a) Let $P$ equal {$x_0, x_1,...,x_n$} and $P'$ equal {$x_0, x_1, x_2,...,x_{j-1}, \gamma, x_j,...,x_n$}

Then $L(f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)\cdot(x_i-x_{i-1})$ $=\sum_{i=1\neq j}^{n}\inf_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f(x)(x_j-\gamma +\gamma-x_{j-1}) \rightarrow (1)$

Now, $\inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f(x)=\inf${$f(x) \mid x\in[x_{j-1}, x_j]$} $\leq \inf${$f(x)\mid x \in{[x_{j-1}}, \gamma]$} and

$\leq\inf${$f(x)\mid x\in[\gamma, x_j]$} $=\inf_{[\gamma, x_j]}f(x)$

$(1)\leq\sum_{i=1\neq j}^{n}\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\inf_{[x_{j-1}, \gamma]}f(x)(\gamma-x_{j-1})+\inf_{[\gamma, x_j]}f(x)(x_j-\gamma)=L(f, P')$

Analogously, $U(f,P)\geq U(f, P')$

b) If $P'$ differs from $P$ by $m$ points, repeat the procedure in a) $m$ times.

QED

**NOTE**

So I understand the concept of partitions, but this proof confuses the hell out of me. 1. What is $P'$ and why is it necessary to consider. 2. What is the lemma actually saying (visually) 3. I don't get the procedure after the second line. ANY help would GREATLY be appreciated, thanks!! :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228504/riemann-integral-upper-vs-lower-estimate-inf-vs-sup does this help? About 3, I don't know which line you are unsure of but I can tell that the proof is to directly compute the lower sum of the one point refinement and compare it against that of the original partition.

Comment: @LiChunMin Thanks, I'll have a look, and it's this line $=\sum_{i=1\neq j}^{n}\inf_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]}f(x)(x_j-\gamma +\gamma-x_{j-1})$

Comment: That is $L(f,P)$. $-\gamma+\gamma = 0 $. The author intented to do this to compare it with $L(f,P')$ later on. It might be easier to see why he did that if you compute $L(f,P')$ first.

Comment: If you have read the thread already, the theorem is saying that if you do refinement, then the gap between upper sum and lower sum will become closer and closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Riemann sums $\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$ (or similar) are **finite sums** referring to a chosen partition ${\cal P}$ of the interval $[a,b]$. But the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$ is a **limit** of such sums when ${\cal P}$ is refined to oblivion (it's more complicated than $n\to\infty$). In order to see what happens "in the limit" we have to study what happens to such a Riemann sum when a partition ${\cal P}$ is refined to a partition ${\cal P}'$ by introducing additional separation points.

**2.** Upper sums clearly overshoot the intended limit, but there is hope: Under  refinement of ${\cal P}$ the upper sum **decreases**, hence the sum computed with the finer partition will be a better approximation to the intended limit. Similarly: Under a refinement the lower sum will **increase**.

**3.** Forget about the machinery set up for the proof of the lemma. The basic idea is very simple indeed.

Assume that an interval $J$ of the partition is split into two intervals $J'$ and $J''$ by an additional separation point. Then $|J|=|J'|+|J''|$, where I have written $|\cdot|$ for the length of these intervals. It follows that
$$\sup_J f\cdot |J|=\sup_J f\cdot \bigl(|J'|+|J''|)\geq\sup_{J'}f\cdot |J'|+\sup_{J''} f\cdot |J''|\ ,\tag{1}$$
because  $\sup f$ over the large interval $J$ tends to be larger than  $\sup f$ over the subintrvals $J'$, $J''$. In $(1)$ the LHS is the contribution of $J$ in $U(f,{\cal P})$, and the RHS is the total contribution of $J$ in $U(f,{\cal P}')$.

Draw a figure!