# How does the infimum/supremum of a sum make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

Consider a function $f$ and partition $P$ of $[a,b]$. Then the upper sum $U$ of $f$ on $P$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
U(f,P)= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})
\end{equation}

Where $M_i=\sup\{ f:t_{i-1}\leq x \leq t_i \}~\forall x\in[a,b]$.

This definition does not bother me. What does, however, is when we consider the following:

\begin{equation}
\inf\{{U(f,P)}\}
\end{equation}

My understanding of the infimum of a set (this would disturb me for supremum also) is the greatest element that is less than or equal to all the other elements in the set.

But $U(f,P)$ is a summation, one that we would expect to result in a value for a given function $f$ and partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ - a set with one element.

So how is $\inf\{{U(f,P)}\}$ not trivial? (or why isn't it just $U(f,P)$?)

I thought that maybe $\inf\{{U(f,P)}\}$, if it existed, would return the smallest contributing part of the summation, but I haven't seen anything that supports this idea.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228504/riemann-integral-upper-vs-lower-estimate-inf-vs-sup does this help?

Comment: For the existence of the upper integral, it suffice to show that $\{U(f,P)\}_{\{P\}}$($\{P\}$ is the set of partition) is nonempty and bounded below.

Comment: It's probably meant to be $\mathrm{inf}_{P} U(f, P)$, where the Infinium is taken over all partitions $P$

Comment: Wow it really does help! To check though, is $\inf\{{U(f,P)}\}$ essentially picking out the 'best' partition so as to minimise the overestimation that $U(f,P)$ introduces?

Comment: the 'best' partition coincides with the 'longer' partition, this is why instead of the infimum it is used the concept of limit too.

Comment: "The best" partition may not exist: there may not be a partition $P$ such that $U(f, P)$ achieves the infimum. It's more just saying "the result has to be at least this large, no matter what partition you use, and furthermore this is the best possible bound".

Comment: That's an abuse of notation. What you really want to say is $$\inf\, \{U(f, P) \mid P\text{ is a partition of }[a, b] \} $$

Answer (score 1):

I think that in that definition you have to consider the infimum of the set of all the lower sums when $P$ is an arbitrary partition of the interval.